Derivative of matrix inverse, perturbed by a scaled identity
Let $A$ be a non-singular matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Consider the map
$$f: t \mapsto ( A + tI)^{-1}$$
A paper I am reading claims that $f'(t) = -A^{-2}$ for small $t$. Is this an approximation or exact? How can I prove it?

Implicit differentiation is one way.

It is an approximation. The exact time derivatives are
$$\eqalign{
\def\q{\quad}
\def\D#1{\frac{d^{#1}F}{dt^{#1}}}
&F=f(t),\q \D{} = -F^{2}, \q \D{2} = 2F^{3},\q \ldots\q \D{n} = (-1)^n : n! , F^{n+1} \
{\rm and}!,&{\rm for;small;}t \
&\lim_{t\to0} : F^n = A^{-n} \
}$$

Actually, $-A^{-2}$ is the derivative at $t=0$. By definition,
$$
f'(0)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{(A+tI)^{-1}-A^{-1}}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{A^{-1}[(I+tA^{-1})^{-1}-I]}{t}
$$
Next, we use the Neumann series (formally the geometric series $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+\dots$, valid for small $x$)
$$
f'(0)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{A^{-1}[I-A^{-1}t+A^{-2}t^2+\dots-I]}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{A^{-1}[-A^{-1}t+A^{-2}t^2+\dots]}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}(-A^{-2}+A^{-3}t+\dots)=-A^{-2}
$$
